# Can't install wordpress 403 ! Access forbidden

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I try to install new wordpress on server. I can run every php file in my directory, or js, css but when i run install.php there is some error. “Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server”. I read so many articles about it but can't resolve my problem !! please someone help me ! Am i doing something wrong or i need permission from hosting owner ?

Comment: Maybe check the chmod setting for the wordpress folder.. just a guess

Comment: its going to be either the http user doesnt have access to the folder (eg. apache/httpd/www-data), or as @meck373 says, itll be a read/write issue generally

Answer (score 1):

This is probably an issue with the permissions of your wordpress files. Try running the below - you may need to run them with the sudo command, depends on your setup:

```
find /path/to/your/wordpress/install/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find /path/to/your/wordpress/install/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

You may also need to change the ownership of the files to the same user and group that the web server is running as, for example:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/your/wordpress/install/
```

Again, you may need to run this as sudo depending on your setup.